# XmlElement reflect

Tags: c#, .net

classes like these two

```
[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class VcRead
{
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public string[] Items;

    [XmlElement("amount")]
    public int Count;
}

public class KeyItem
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int ID;

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Title;
}
```

now,i wanna use reflection to get all fields and their Xml Mark.
it's easy to get the fields' name and their values.
but,how to get the XmlElement's value,such as "amount" in

```
[XmlElement("amount")]
public int Count;
```

Comment: GetCustomAttributes method of PropertyInfo type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Type type = typeof(VcRead);
foreach (var fiedInfo in type.GetFields())
{
    // your field

    foreach (var attribute in fiedInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true))
    {
        // attributes
    }                   
}
```

To get element name from `XmlElementAttribute` (same approach for `XmlAttributeAttribute`):

```
if (attribute is XmlElementAttribute)
{
    var elementName = ((XmlElementAttribute)attribute).ElementName;
}
```

Also keep in mind that your classes have public fields instead of properties.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of XmlElement use the XmlElementAttribute as like below

```
[XmlElementAttribute("test")]
 public string Test  {get;set;};
```

Then, Access the GetProperties() of this object through reflection

```
 PropertyInfo[] methods = typeof(KeyItem).GetProperties();


 foreach (PropertyInfo method in methods)
 {
  // Use of Attribute.GetCustomAttributes which you can access the attributes
    Attribute[] attribs = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(method, typeof(XmlAttribute));
 }
```